# putting non-state value in flink processor

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I started putting some non-state member variables in processor because I needed to parameterize the processor at initialization. For example,

```
public class MyProcessor extends KeyedProcessorFunction<String, Event, Event2> {
    private int param;

    public MyProcessor(int param) {
        this.param = param
    }
    ...
}
```

Ok, now I need to put some reference data

```
public class MyProcessor extends KeyedProcessorFunction<String, Event, Event2> {
    private Map<String, Integer> ref;

    public MyProcessor(Map<String, Integer> ref) {
        this.ref = ref  // I promise to not to change the map
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this ok? something feels off. If flink can serialize non-state member variables for checkpointing and whatnot, why do we need state variables to begin with? If param or ref variable changes during processElement, it won't get synced but is it still safe to use them as long as I don't change them?

Thanks in advance